# Multiple column condition in data table

Tags: r, data.table

I was trying to find a better solution to test multiple columns on `NA` in `datatable` simultaneously, but without success. Assume I have a `datatable` called TDT and it has columns x1 to x10, which should be tested to be non-NA. I am using the following syntax:

```
TDT[,natest := ifelse(!is.na(x1) & !is.na(x2) & !is.na(x3) & !is.na(x4) & !is.na(x5) & !is.na(x6) & !is.na(x7) & !is.na(x8) & !is.na(x9) & !is.na(x10), 1, 0)]
```

Can this be written more concisely?

Data:

```
set.seed(1)
TDT <- data.table(
              x1 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
              x2 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
              x3 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
              x4 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
              x5 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
              x6 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
              x7 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
              x8 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
              x9 = c(rep(NA,50),rep(0.1,50)),
              x10 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2))
```

Comment: Fair enough, made an edit to account for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` together with `.SD` like this:

```
TDT[, natest := +(!is.na(Reduce("+", .SD)))]
```

`Reduce` takes the the list of variables provided by `.SD` (which is the entire data.table) and performs the `+` operation. The result is then tested with `is.na` and converted to a binary variable (0, 1 stored as an integer)  with `+()`.

As Frank's comment suggests, this method assumes that the columns are all numeric. To select specific columns for this test, you can use `.SDcols`.

To make this more robust, you can make a copy of the data.table as a logical matrix, convert that to a data.table and perform the operation:

```
TDT[, natest := +(Reduce("+", data.table(!is.na(TDT))) == length(TDT))]
```

Here, if only checking a subset of the columns, then `data.table(!is.na(TDT))` and `length(TDT)` would need to be adjusted.

Comment: And if `.SD` has some nonnumeric columns?

Comment: Indeed, would be also interesting to see how this can be done in case of nonnumerics.

Comment: The second version should work for non-numeric columns as long as the values are truly NA.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shorter version

```
library(data.table)
TDT[, natest := as.numeric(!apply(.SD, 1, anyNA))]
```

Second option that is faster

```
TDT[, natest := as.numeric(!is.na(do.call(pmin, .SD)))]
```

Comment: Interesting, why do you use `do.call(pmin, .SD)` instead of `apply(.SD,1,min)`, which apparently leads to the same outcome?

Comment: @user3032689 `apply` is typically slow and should be avoided if there is a different method.  With a small data set there isn't much difference, but when the data set grows in size using `do.call` will be substantially faster.